# How to worship Kalabhairava?

Tags: bhairava

How to worship Kalabhairava (or Bhairava in general) as someone ordinary, not initiated into Tantra?

All I know is Kalabhairava Ashtakam and importance of the observance of Kalashtami.

I have seen the videos of Rajarshi Nandy who promotes Bhairava Upasana which are very helpful.  I am looking for authoritative texts relating to Kalabhairava Upasana which I can refer.  For example what are the offerings given to the Lord, Stotras, methods of Upasana, fasting etc.

Also is there a Kalabhairava Kavacham?  Anyone know of the source of the same?

Comment: What is the purpose for your Worship?